# ¿archivos *.do en vez de jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

estoy ayudando en el desarrollo de una aplicación, hecha con java y jsp. Los enlaces aparecen como .do en vez de .jsp, a pesar de que los archivos son .jsp. Lo máximo que he podido averiguar es que tiene que ver con struts o algo así dicha extensión, pero mi duda es si yo creo un nuevo archivo .jsp, cómo y dónde tengo que configurarlo para luego poder abrirlo. Siento la ambiguedad, a ver si al menos me podéis aportar información sobre dicha extensión.

Gracias a Pablo he encontrado el fichero "struts-config.xml", y he configurado mi jsp "mostrarCargos.jsp" de la siguiente manera, pero sigue sin funcionar por lo que falta algo mas.

```
<global-forwards>
        <forward name="MostrarCargos"
            path="/WEB-INF/page/administracion/mostrarCargos.jsp" />
</global-forwards>
<action-mappings>
        <action path="/MostrarCargos" forward="/mostrarCargos.jsp" />
</action-mappings>
```

Comment: Debe ser una aplicación muy antigua: Existe Struts y Struts2, ambos son frameworks ya bastante anticuados y en desuso. Realmente cuando haces una petición HTTP, la URL no tiene por qué tener extensión, pero las acciones (Actions) de Struts suelen estar *mapeadas* usando .do al final. Tienes que tener un fichero struts.xml o struts-config.xml donde relaciona las Acciones con las URLs

Comment: Efectivamente, es una aplicación bastante antigua. He conseguido encontrar el fichero al que te refieres "struts-config.xml", en su interior hay global-forwards y action-mapping. He intentado configurar mi jsp "mostrarCargos.jsp" pero sigue saliendome error 404. por lo que a mi configuracion le debe faltar algo más.

Comment: ¿Que versión de struts estás utilizando?

Comment: En el doctype del archivo "struts-config.xml" dice la 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Struts tu puedes llegar a un jsp, por medio de un **Action(Controller)** de la siguiente forma:

```
    <action path="/MuestraCargos"
        type="com.mkyong.common.action.MostrarCargosAction"
        name="MostrarCargosForm">
    </action>
```

y en mi clase action solamente hacer referencia al **forward**, que tienes configurado en los  **global-forwards**, de la siguiente manera:

```
       public class MostrarCargosAction extends Action{

           public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
              HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
              throws Exception {

                return mapping.findForward("MostrarCargos");
           }

        }
```

lo que hará que se redireccione a /WEB-INF/page/administracion/mostrarCargos.jsp, y la forma de llamarlo en la url será:

```
     http://localhost:8080/tuContexto/MuestraCargos.do
```

La otra forma es como lo tienes configurado, por medio de un **Action** pero sin una clase, con lo que tienes configurado en los **action-mappings**:

```
       <action path="/MostrarCargos" forward="/mostrarCargos.jsp" />
```

La forma de llamarlo es ligeramente diferente al final MostrarCargos.do

```
       http://localhost:8080/tuContexto/MostrarCargos.do
```

El error que te marca del 404, es porque esta buscando en **webapp** o **WebContent** el jsp **mostrarCargos.jsp**, lo puedes configurar como el que tienes en los **global-forwards** que redireccione hacia **/WEB-INF/page/administracion/mostrarCargos.jsp** o poner el jsp en la carpeta **webapp** o **WebContent** directamente.